# How do I find the .desktop information for a given binary?

Tags: gnome, python, programming

Given the path to an executable (say `/usr/bin/gvim`), how can I find the Gnome .desktop file for that application?

I'm futzing around in python, so a python-specific answer would be most helpful.

Comment: I've poked around with [the Gnome docs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/references), but I haven't found anything for querying the existing set of [desktop entries](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gnome-desktop/2.32/gnome-desktop-GnomeDesktopItem.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do it programmatically, use python-gmenu.  It wraps the libgnome-menu2 API for Python.

That API lets you iterate over all the desktop directories that are currently configured and includes any overrides or modifications the user has customized.  Then you just query each file to see if it's Exec line matches what you expect.

I couldn't find any documentation for either library, but liberal use of "import gmenu; dir(gmenu)" and looking over /usr/include/gnome-menus/gmenu-tree.h should help.

Comment: Excellent! That's exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If your package is installed from package (not from source), you can use (in Bash):

```
dpkg -L $(dpkg -S /usr/bin/pidgin | cut -f1 -d: ) | grep \.desktop$
```

In the case of `gvim`, it outputs nothing. You have another problem, in fact, `gvim` is an *alternative*. The "true" `gvim` can be multiple programs. On my computer it is `/usr/bin/vim.gnome`. Let's try with it. This doesn't work either... because there is no `.desktop` in the same package that `vim.gnome`. In fact, in this complicated case, the `.desktop` is in another package common to all graphical interfaces of Vim: `vim-gui-common`

Answer (score 1):

The .desktop files for most applications are stored in:

```
/usr/share/applications
```

some .desktop files may also be stored in:

```
/usr/local/share/applications
```

or (for per user settings) in:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

Comment: Can't .desktop also be installed in the user's home directory? I'd rather not walk every file in every possible install location to track down a path if it's available from some service.

Comment: See edit. The location of .desktop files cannot be extracted from the installation path, I'm afraid (but should be defined in the .deb package).

Answer (score 1):

You can search through all desktop files. For example, to find the desktop file related to `gedit`:

```
grep -li exec=gedit $(locate -r '\.desktop$')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execut  1.`sudo find /path_to_folder/ -iname *.desktop` in general. And  2.`sudo find / -iname *.desktop` in your case.